# Java Applet to run the java files from my workspace

Tags: java, applet

I have 5 java files with some scripts. I would like to have a button and a drop-down, so that if you select any file and press the button, that java file should run.
I have no idea of applet.
Can you please help?
I have started writing a small program but not sure how to proceed further.

```
package com;

import java.applet.Applet;

import java.awt.*;

public class HelloApplet extends Applet{

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Hello Applet", 260, 260);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Just [Google it](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-applet) many tutorials out there !! and by seeing your requirements I think applet is really not required

Comment: Is your requirement to simply have a graphical user interface that allows you to select a java class and run it? Or do you want to explicitly use an applet because you want to provide this functionality in a browser?
Meaning: do you really need to use an applet?

Comment: As @EddyG asked, do you really need an applet? Use of in browser Java has dropped for quite a few years in favor of Javascript, especially from the quite serious security flaw that was uncovered a few years back.

Comment: @Eddy you are right. I just need an UI that allows me to select the file and run it. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: @Vasu Well, that "idea how to do it" is outlined in my answer. Turn to the tutorials, learn how to create a JFrame for example, add a listbox and a button to that, ...

Comment: yes got it... I am on my way!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are just mentioning "applet" because you heard somewhere that applets support a graphical user interface ... I am suggesting that you simply forget about applets. Applets are only interesting if you intend to run your GUI within a browser; but simply spoken - the idea of applets is dead.

So, what you actually want to do is to build a small application that has a graphical user interface. For doing that, you can be either using the older Java Swing libraries 
( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ ); or the relatively new JavaFx stuff 
( http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm ).

It will take some time to learn about these concepts, but it is worth investing the time.